# SQL server security

Tags: sql-server

I have requirement that I need to take backup from production and need to restore it in development.

I have taken all users and permissions from production by generating scripts, but two users are facing an issue in the development copy because they do not have permission to `CREATE`,`ALTER` and `EXECUTE`. When I used the generate script feature to get their permissions from production, they are only `db_reader` and `db_writer`. But now they are getting errors like "execute permissions denied in stored procedure". Prior they were able to `CREATE` ,`ALTER`, and `DROP` stored procedures successfully.

How is this possible? My question is will the `db_writer` role allow a user to `CREATE` and `DROP` stored procedures?

Comment: Are you sure you did backup/restore? Restored database has all the permissions of the original database. The only permissions that backup/restore of user db does not transfer are server level permissions

Comment: Yes I have restored. Other users in the database are fine ,only two users facing issue

Comment: My question is db_writer will create ,drop, alter the stored procedure

Comment: Are these users Windows users or created from SQL Server logins?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is db_writer will create ,drop, alter the stored procedure

The answer is `NO`.

`db_datawriter` can only do `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.

There could be a case when some user was the `owner` of that database, so it had the permissions of `db_owner` in this database, and after `restore` the `owner` was changed, but it cannot be your case as you have two users that now have not `EXECUTE` permission.